# Violation of DRY principle in Java

Tags: java, dry

I have three methods that filter an array of devices by a field.

```
public void filtrateByType(Device[] devices, String type) {
    if (devices == null) {
        return;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < devices.length; i++) {
        if (devices[i] == null) {
            continue;
        }

        if (devices[i].getType() == null && type == null) {
            continue;
        } else if (devices[i].getType() == null) {
            devices[i] = null;
            continue;
        }

        if (!devices[i].getType().equals(type)) {
            devices[i] = null;
        }
    }
}
```

The other methods are similar. The only difference is calling another getter of field on which filtering is applied. For example, there is a call to `getModel()` instead `getType()`. Does this violate the DRY principle and how can I change it such that it doesn't (without generics)?

**P.S.**
It's a homework and unfortunatelly we don't use generics yet. I also can't change the signature of methods. I have a clue that I can create inner class with one method that will call needed getter and return a value. So, I need to put all my checks inside this method, but I don't really understand how do it with my logic (especially with "continue").

Comment: "_without generics_"? You can, but why?

Comment: My guess is this guy is still starting out and generics is a bit of an advanced topic if so. You have to learn to walk before you can run :)

Comment: You can use the strategy pattern https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create an `interface DeviceValueExtractor` that looks like this:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface DeviceValueExtractor {
    Object extractValue(Device device);
}
```

Now rewrite your method to:

```
public void filterByType(Device[] devices, DeviceValueExtractor extractor, Object expect) {
    if (devices == null) {
        return;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < devices.length; i++) {
        if (devices[i] == null) {
            continue;
        }
        Object actual = extractor.extractValue(devices[i]);
        if (actual == null && expect== null) {
            continue;
        } else if (actual  == null) {
            devices[i] = null;
            continue;
        }
        if (!Objects.equals(actual, expect)) {
            devices[i] = null;
        }
    }
 }
```

Usage:

```
filterByType(devices, Device::getType, "Hello");
```

---

**Note:** I used `Object` due to the requirement not to have generics - because the only method called is `equals` this is actually No Big Deal.

However for some more type safety, you can introduce generics (and do away with `DeviceValueExtractor`:

```
public static <T> void filterByType(Device[] devices, Function<Device, T> extractor, T expect) {
    if (devices == null) {
        return;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < devices.length; i++) {
        if (devices[i] == null) {
            continue;
        }
        Object actual = extractor.apply(devices[i]);
        if (actual == null && expect== null) {
            continue;
        } else if (actual  == null) {
            devices[i] = null;
            continue;
        }
        if (!Objects.equals(actual, expect)) {
            devices[i] = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a some Java 8 magic would help here:

```
public void filtrateByType(Device[] devices, String type) {
    filtrateBy(devices, Device::getType, type);
}

public void filtrateBy(Device[] devices, Function<? super Device, String> attributeGetter, String attribute) {
    if (devices == null) {
        return;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < devices.length; i++) {

        if (devices[i] == null) {
            continue;
        }

        if (attributeGetter.apply(devices[i]) == null && attribute == null) {
            continue;
        } else if (attributeGetter.apply(devices[i]) == null) {
            devices[i] = null;
            continue;
        }
        if (!attributeGetter.apply(devices[i]).equals(attribute)) {
            devices[i] = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well it is using a generic interface, but it could be worse, the proper way to declare that function would be: `public <E, T> void filtrateBy(E[] devices, Function<? super E, ? extends T> attributeGetter, T attribute)`, but I decided to not use that since the autor requested no generics.

Comment: The author requested no generics, so you decided to use less generics than you normally would - i.e. bad generics. Not sure I follow... P.S. all the wildcards are totally unneccessary.

Comment: Well, taht depends on *why* the author requested no generics. Maybe it's for a homework where they are forbidden from using generics, but SO isn't a site to do your homework for you, so that's not a problem.
If they are a new programmer and are confused by the generics, using less generics can be a good way for them to understand the basics and stop being afraid of generics and wildcard.
Finally, the only "legit" reason is using an older version of Java that doesn't support generics, but I already started my answer by "using Java 8 magic", clearly stating this solution is for Java 8+ only.

Comment: I still don't follow. If I asked a question and said "I'm using Java 8, please stick to that" would you use Java 10 features under the justification that it's not Java 11? Sorry, but I really think that the question is very clear as asked and this does not answer it.

Answer (score 0):

This is simpler version. You can use raw types, but this would be more error prone.

```
public static <T> void filtrateByType(T[] objects, Function<T, String> function, String type) {
    if (objects == null || type == null)
        return;
    for (int i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {
        if (objects[i] == null) continue;
        String match = function.apply(objects[i]);
        if (match == null || !match.equals(type)) 
            objects[i] = null;
    }
}
```

However, I suspect what you really want is to use the Stream API

```
Device[] filtered = Stream.of(devices)
                          .filter(d -> Objects.equals(d.getType(), type))
                          .toArray(Device[]::new);
```

Comment: The rawtypes suggestion makes me sad ... I like my generic free approach more.

Comment: That's fair - but I suppose one can desugar the method reference if required. I was going to write implementations of the extractor, perhaps put them in a enum, etc - but decided that it wouldn't add a huge amount to the answer.

Comment: While the Stream approach is nice, it seems like the problem space is to update the array in place. Wouldn't the Stream example create a new array that cannot be returned from the existing method (as the existing method is declared void)? Or am I misunderstanding something here?

Comment: @KevinO that is true, however `null`ing out values in an array to implement a filter is relatively ugly compared to creating an array of only the elements you need.